# Euler Cauchy equations, change of variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

To convert an euler cauchy: $x^{2}y''+pxy'+qy=0$ equation into a linear one we perfom the substitution $x = e^z$ from which we get:
$$z=\log x$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} z} = e^z =x $$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{1}{x}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z}\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z}\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}} y}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}} = \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}) = \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z}\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x})$$

Using product rule:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}} y}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}} = \frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x}\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z}) + (\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z})\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x})$$
$$= (\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x})\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z}(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}) + \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z}\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}} z}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}$$
$$= (\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x})\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z}((\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z})(\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x})) + \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z}\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}} z}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}$$

If I use the product rule again I get:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}} y}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}} = (\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x})[(\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x})\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}} y}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}} + (\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z})\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z}(\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x})] + \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z}\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}} z}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}$$

Now if I rewrite the last term in the square bracket as 
$$(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z})\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} z}) = (\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z})\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(1) = 0 $$ I get the correct answer but we know that $\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x} = e^{-z}$ hence $(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z})\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z}(\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x}) = (\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} z}) \frac{-1}{x}$ from which my answer is incorrect.
How do I resolve this contradiction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot swap the operator order here, i.e. $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dz}\right) \ne \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz} \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)$ in general, since $z$ and $x$ are related.

Comment: Okay I get this. But the problem I am facing is that if I resolve $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} z}\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x}$ by putting in $\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{1}{x} = e^{-z}$ it doesn't change the equation into a linear one and is hence incorrect. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac1x\frac{dy}{dz}\right) = -\frac1{x^2}\frac{dy}{dz} + \frac1x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dz}\right) = 
-\frac1{x^2}\frac{dy}{dz} + \frac1x^2\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{dy}{dz}\right),
$$
(just use that $\frac{d}{dx}=\frac1x\frac{d}{dz}$) and
$$
x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{d^2 y}{dz^2} - \frac{dy}{dz}.
$$
Now rewrite equation as
$$
y'' - y' + py' + qy = 0
$$
and solve by usual methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what I wanted to know was what is it that I am doing wrong by the second method.